# php dom Xml loop throught elements preserve childrens

Tags: php, xml, dom, children

So i have an Xml file like

```
<cars>
    <id>1</id>
    <photos>
        <img>http://sit.com/img.jpg</img>
        <img>http://sit.com/img.jpg</img>
        <img>http://sit.com/img.jpg</img>
        <img>http://sit.com/img.jpg</img>
    </photos>
</cars>
```

So i need to change all tag name to alternative and i need get something like

```
<cars>
    <ex_id>1</ex_id>
    <images>
        <photo>http://sit.com/img.jpg</photo>
        <photo>http://sit.com/img.jpg</photo>
        <photo>http://sit.com/img.jpg</photo>
        <photo>http://sit.com/img.jpg</photo>
    </images>
</cars>
```

My code is

```
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('cars') as $item) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < $item->childNodes->length; ++$i) {
        $car = $item->childNodes->item($i);
        $NewElement = $dom->createElement($newName,$value);
        $car->parentNode->replaceChild($NewElement->cloneNode(TRUE), $car); 
    }
}
```

Do something like that

```
<cars>
    <ex_id>1</ex_id>
    <images/>
</cars>
```

So it cut all childrens of `<photos>`, so my question is how to preserve children and also change childrens tags from `<img>` to `<photo>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are several issues:

1. getElementByTagName() and $childNodes return 'live' lists, they change if you change the DOM. You can use iterator_to_array() to copy them into an array.
2. Here are not only element nodes. Comments, cdata sections and text (even containing only whitespaces) are nodes, too. If you iterate $childNodes you will have to validate the DOMNode::$nodeType.
3. Do not use the second argument of DOMDocument::createElement(). It has a broken escaping. Create a text node and append it.

1 and 2 go away if you use Xpath to fetch the nodes.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

foreach ($xpath->evaluate('/cars/images/img') as $photo) {
   $newNode = $dom->createElement('photo');
   $newNode->appendChild($dom->createTextNode($photo->textContent));
   $photo->parentNode->replaceChild($newNode, $photo);
}

echo $dom->saveXml();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<cars>
    <ex_id>1</ex_id>
    <images>  
       <photo>http://sit.com/img.jpg</photo>
       <photo>http://sit.com/img.jpg</photo>
       <photo>http://sit.com/img.jpg</photo>
       <photo>http://sit.com/img.jpg</photo>
    </images>
</cars>
```

Changing an DOM document is often a bad idea. It is easier to extract data from a source document and build a new target document:

```
$source = new DOMDocument();
$source->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($source);

$target = new DOMDocument();
$target->formatOutput = TRUE;

$cars = $target->appendChild($target->createElement('cars'));
$cars 
  ->appendChild($target->createElement('ex_id'))
  ->appendChild(
      $target->createTextNode(
        $xpath->evaluate('string(/cars/id)')
      )
    );

$images = $cars->appendChild($target->createElement('images'));

foreach ($xpath->evaluate('/cars/photos/img') as $photo) {
  $images
    ->appendChild($target->createElement('photo'))
    ->appendChild($target->createTextNode($photo->textContent));
}

echo $target->saveXml();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<cars>
  <ex_id>1</ex_id>
  <images>
    <photo>http://sit.com/img.jpg</photo>
    <photo>http://sit.com/img.jpg</photo>
    <photo>http://sit.com/img.jpg</photo>
    <photo>http://sit.com/img.jpg</photo>
  </images>
</cars>
```

Here is a language dedicated to transforming XML - **XSLT**. XSLT is supported by PHPs `ext/xsl`.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but i think you dont understand what i want to do. I cant change my code beacause then i need to change all my project. I just need to add two strings to my existing code to fix my problem